# $L_2$ convergence a of a product $\phi_n \psi_n$

Tags: real-analysis

We have two sequences $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ that converge in the $L_2$ norm to two functions $f$ and $g$ (all the functions here are functions $\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. I can't prove that 
$$
\int \phi_n \psi_n \to \int f g 
$$

where, if necessary, we considered sub-sequences of the original sequences.

Thanks in andvance for your answers.

Comment: Hint: Say $(x_n)$ and $y_n$ are sequences of reals, $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$. You should be familiar with the little algebraic trick needed to  show that $x_ny_n\to xy$; exactly the same trick works here.

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* This follows from
$$ \int (\phi_n \psi_n - fg)  = \int \phi_n (\psi_n - g) + \int (\phi_n - f) g $$
Then use Hölder and conclude.